# order by two distinct rows in one query

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Question for a proof of concept here:

Basically I want to combine the following two queries into one:

```
SELECT `cat` FROM `test` group by `cat` order by `catSort`,`ID` desc
$cat-->  SELECT * FROM `test` where `cat`=$cat group by `cat2` order by `cat2Sort`,`ID` desc
```

Let me elaborate. Suppose I have the following table `test`:

```
-----------------------------------------
| ID | cat  | cat2 | catSort | cat2Sort |
|----------------------------------------
| 1  | cat  | sub  | 0       | 0        |
| 2  | cat  | sub2 | 0       | 1        |
| 3  | cat  | sub  | 0       | 1        |
| 4  | cat2 | sub  | 1       | 0        |
| 5  | cat2 | sub2 | 1       | 0        |
| 6  | cat  | sub2 | 0       | 0        |
----------------------------------------
```

What this does is it has two categories where `cat2` is a subcategory of `cat` and `cat` is sorted by `catSort` and `cat2` is sorted by, you guessed it, `cat2Sort`.
The hierarchy of this should look like this:

```
cat
  sub  ID:1
  sub  ID:3
  sub2 ID:6
  sub2 ID:2
cat2
  sub  ID:4
  sub2 ID:5
```

How can I achieve this by NOT `order by catSort, cat2Sort` as the sort is being added later.
They need to be ordered by it's `ID` so that newly added entries go to the bottom but at the same time sort by the sort fields if they are set. eg `order by catSort, cat2Sort, ID`.

Also I need to group them in another query in order to get this:

```
cat
  sub  ID:1
  sub2 ID:6
cat2
  sub  ID:4
  sub2 ID:5
```

My initial thought was to group two fields together and group by them. Something like:

```
SELECT *, combine(`cat`,`cat2`) as `tempCat` FROM `test`
group by `tempCat` order by `catSort`,`serSort`,`ID` desc
```

But of course that's completely made up.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

Use can sort by two columns as bellow

```
ORDER BY `column1` ASC/DESC, `column2` ASC/DESC
```

Comment: `How can I archive this by NOT order by catSort, cat2Sort as the sort is being added later` ... yes I know but that would just be... to easy wouldn't it? ;) thanks anyway